# organizing objects by name

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Take the array of objects below "toursByHotels" — I want to take this data and get the sum of tours for each object that has the same name (the hotel's name, ie. Marriott, etc).

Is there an easier way in d3 than having to create 5 new arrays with the same names, then sum the tours of those?

```js
var toursByHotel = [
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Marriott",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Springhill",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Residence",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Residence",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Residence",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Residence",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Courtyard",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 1,
          "tours": 10
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 2,
          "tours": 15
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 3,
          "tours": 8
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 4,
          "tours": 12
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 5,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 6,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 7,
          "tours": 40
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 8,
          "tours": 33
        },
        {
          "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 9,
          "tours": 25
        },
        {
         "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 10,
          "tours": 21
        },
        {
         "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 11,
          "tours": 18
        },
        {
         "name": "Renaissance",
          "month": 12,
          "tours": 14
        }
      ];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and return object where each key is hotel name and value is sum of tours. [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/795/)

```js
data = data.reduce(function(obj, e) {
  obj[e.name] = (obj[e.name] || 0) + e.tours;
  return obj;
}, {});

console.log(data)
```

If you want to get sum and percentage for each hotel you can do it like this [**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/797/)

```js
var result = {}

var total = data.reduce((a, b) => {return a + b.tours }, 0);
data.forEach(function(e) {
  if(!this[e.name]) {
    this[e.name] = {sum: e.tours, percentage: 0}
    result[e.name] = this[e.name];
  }
  this[e.name].sum += e.tours;
  this[e.name].percentage = (this[e.name].sum / total)*100;
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Comment: it says "e" is undefined...getting a lot of errors with this code.

Comment: — yea, true it does work in the fiddle. for some reason when i try it in my code I get "result is not defined"

Comment: @Krang I just figured i posted wrong code here, please try again with this code, or copy code from fiddle.

Comment: ha yea I found the updated code in the fiddle earlier — and still getting "result is not defined". it works fine in the fiddle though...i'm not sure why "result" is an issue...

Comment: — here's is a fiddle with the full code http://codepen.io/mcKrack/pen/Vaggxq?editors=0010 . Watch out for the variable "total", which i am using for something else already.

Comment: I also created one object called `result` to store data so i think now it works http://codepen.io/anon/pen/XdGKxO?editors=0110

Answer (score 1):

Using reduce would be the best way to do this:

[Working Example](https://jsbin.com/napucu/3/edit?js,console)

```
// lets keep track of the total here:
var total = 0;

var totals = a.reduce(function(curr, next) {
  curr[next.name] = (curr[next.name] || 0) + next.tours;
  // increment total here:
  total += next.tours;
  return curr;
}, {});

for (var hotel in totals) {
  var obj = {};
  obj.name = totals[hotel];
  obj.percentage = (totals[hotel] / total) * 100 + '%';
  totals[hotel] = obj;
}
```

[MDN docs on .reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: @JoranHendrix — thank you — from this if i were to have a sum total of all those numbers saved to a variable (total), how would i figure out what percentage of the total each hotel's tours make up?

Comment: hey I know you have selected an answer, but I really don't like the complexity there, I am updating my answer with a much more straightforward approach...